# Are these Microsoft programs necessary for my computer?

Tags: windows-xp

- Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime Native v1.0 (x86)
- Microsoft User-Mode  Driver Framework
  Feature Pack 1.0
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2005
  Redistributable
- Microsoft XNA Framework
  Redistributable 2.0

There are other parts included with these but they are all related. I don't use any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all frameworks, so *in theory* you don't need them but software that requires a certain framework will not run without it installed. Generally, unless you have a real pressing need to remove them they are unlikely to do any harm nor damage performance and I would recommend keeping them.

@firedfly has already mentioned the Visual C++ Redistributable (and yes, I agree that you really should really keep this one).

The [User-Mode Driver Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Mode_Driver_Framework) is also pretty important, as it allows some drivers to run in "user mode" (by providing an API for the kernal instead of the driver having direct access), which helps protect the system if they fail. I'm not sure if these drivers *require* the framework, but I would guess they do.

The [XNA Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) is used in the construction of some games (XNA being a game development studio / toolset), so without the redistributable you will be unable to run games that requires this.

Similarly, the [Sync Framework Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework) works on the same priciples, but again for a different set of software.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of applications depend on *Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable*.  I would not recommend removing it.  If you do, applications may stop functioning.  I'm not sure about the others.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the User-mode driver framework, none of those programmers are necessary or have any value *by themselves*.   However, all of them are likely necessary for the correct operation of at least one other non-Microsoft program on your system.  It is possible that you have installed such an application and since removed it, such that they are no longer necessary, but it's not a good idea to remove them.

Comment: OK I'll keep them then.